# Display JavaScript Array Elements inside Div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

There's a textarea in the webpage to enable user to add address. User may enter 'n' number of addresses by clicking on the Add Address button. When user clicks on the Display Address button, all the addresses entered should be displayed inside the "result" div tag as per following format:
**Address 1**

Address entered by user

**Address 2**

Address entered by user

.....

Here's the HTML code

```
<div id="body" align="left">
    <h2>Address Details</h2>
    Enter the Address : <textarea id="address"></textarea><br>
    <button id="add" onclick="addAddress();">Add Address</button>
    <button id="display" onclick="displayAddress();">Display Address</button>
</div>
<div id="result" align="right"></div>
```

Here's the JS function to accept the address and store it in an array:

```
var address = [];

function addAddress(){
    var addr = document.getElementById("address");
    if(addr.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'') !=="") {
        address.push(addr.value);
        addr.value = ""; 
    }           
}
```

And here's the function to display the address inside the result div in the specified format (which does not work)

```
function displayAddress(){
    var display = [];
    var addrno = [];
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    for(var i=0; i<address.length; i++){
        display[i] = address[i];
        addrno[i] = "Address "+(i+1);
    }
    result.innerHTML = addrno[i]+"<br>"+display[i]+"<br>";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, if I understand your question correctly, you could try doing something like this:

```
function displayAddress(){
    var display = [];
    var addrno = [];
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    for(var i=0; i<address.length; i++){
        display[i] = address[i];
        addrno[i] = "Address "+(i+1);
        result.innerHTML += addrno[i]+"<br>"+display[i]+"<br>";
    }
}
```

All I changed was move `result.innerHTML += addrno[i]+"<br>"+display[i]+"<br>";` inside your for loop so it can access the variable `i` uppon each itteration and changed it so it added the string `addrno[i]+"<br>"+display[i]+"<br>";` to the DOM by using `+=` on `result.innerHTML` rather than `=` (so it doesn't override it, rather it appends to it)